# vector basis orthogonal to a vector and orthogonal to A matrix

Tags: orthogonality

I have a vector $V1$, another vector $V2$, and a Matrix $M$, if I want $V2$ to be orthogonal to $V1$ I have to use Gram-Schmidt $$V2'=V2-\frac{V1.V2}{V1.V1}*V1$$ if I want V2 to be **M-Orthogonal** to V1 I use $$V2'=V2-(transpose(V1)*M*V2)*V1$$

what I want to get is combination of both characteristics above, i.e. I want $V2$ to be **orthogonal AND M-Orthogonal** to $V1$ at the same time how should I do that?